# iOS - Split string into keywords and phrases

Tags: swift

So I'm using FireStore as my backend. I have a field called keywords where by users can search for products without needing to type the whole item name i.e. "Strawberry cake" would be saved as so:

```
0 "s"
1 "st"
2 "str"
3 "stra"
4 "straw"
```

However the issue is the full term - *Strawberry cake*  would be saved as so:

```
56 "strawberrycake"
```

But I would also like this result to appear when users just type *"cake"* however due to the term cake not being stored or the term cake split into separate characters, this isn't possible.
This is the code I currently have:

```
extension Array {
    func splitted(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        var splittedArray = [[Element]]()
        if self.count >= size {
        for index in 0...self.count {
            if index % size == 0 && index != 0 {
                splittedArray.append(Array(self[(index - size)..<index]))
            } else if (index == self.count){
                splittedArray.append(Array(self[index - 1..<index]))
            }
        }
        } else {
            splittedArray.append(Array(self[0..<self.count]))
        }
        return splittedArray
    }
}
```

I reckon the function would need to detect whitespaces and split into characters whatever is after the white space then eliminate the white space for the full search term? That's my theory.

And idea of how I can achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you please edit your question and add a clear example of the input and the expected output? There is no array in your question.

Comment: If you have data in your Firestore you can get these and working on "search bar" at swift. I think this is solve your question.